# Path specific cookies in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I'm working on a minisite generator managed in one app.

Each minisite would have its own authentication.

With subdomains, I'm able to be specifically logged in and have settings for only one minisite but not another.

Now, I would like to have a failover where each minisite is accessible without setting up subdomains : `http://mygenerator/minisites/1123`

Is it possible for cookies to be scoped at the `minisite/` path level ?

Or, is there a way to dynamically tweak the cookie key in a `before_filter` at the controller level ?

I took a look at the `:path` option in `session_store` config, but I don't think it's relevant, and it screws up Devise in a redirection loop.

Thanks !

Comment: Hacking the cookie feels pretty heavy handed, plus cookie storage is limited so storing multiple logins to the same cookie is not a good idea either. Why don't you pursue the subdomain option? That would seem to be the most sensible approach.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. That would be an extra feature to avoid the requirement of setting up subdomains to use the app.

Comment: This is my point: Why is setting up subdomains a hard requirement? Is it the wild-card cert price? It sounds like you are wanting to do 3 hours of work so you can save yourself the trouble of 1 hour.

Comment: I totally agree with you, it already works with subdomains, I just wanted to make it work in seconds for the final user with a deployment, say, on Heroku, where wildcard subdomains are not usable out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a late reply but i havent found anything in the internet answering this question.

My problem was that the application always running on a subpath but the session cookie was always issued to /
For me this was fixed by setting and using `Rails.application.config.x.base_url`
for your specific problem you can figure the path to set from the `request` object given in the method

This needs to be added in a new file in your rails Applcation `./config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
  module SessionPath
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
          alias_method :set_cookie_original, :set_cookie
          alias_method :set_cookie, :set_cookie_extended
        end
      end

      def set_cookie_extended(request, session_id, cookie)
        cookie[:path] = Rails.application.config.x.base_url #or what you need
        set_cookie_original(request, session_id, cookie)
      end

    end

ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore.send(:include, SessionPath)
```